# How to backup Microsoft SQL Server database to create multiple 100MB .bak files

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-backups

One `.bak` file:

```
BACKUP DATABASE dbName TO DISK = C:\dbname.bak   1200 MB
```

How to backup Microsoft SQL Server database into multiple `.bak` files, splinting it to multiple files like  `DBName01.bak`,`DBName02.bak`,....'`DBName0N.bak` there `N` is parameter for number of files.

Where `N` would be dynamic parameter.

Comment: I just don't get it? why would someone down vote a proper legit question like this? could you please explain ?

Comment: It wasn't me and questions for me was important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can take your backups to multiple files, its actually more convenient to have smaller files rather than having one large file.

The syntax for taking backups to multiple files would be:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [dbName] TO  
  DISK = N'D:\backups\MultipleFiles\MyDB_Backup_File1.bak',  
  DISK = N'D:\backups\MultipleFiles\MyDB_Backup_File2.bak',  
  DISK = N'D:\backups\MultipleFiles\MyDB_Backup_File3.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'dbName-Full Database Backup'
       , SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

The data is distributed equally among all the files, so if you want smaller files use more files to take backups.

Comment: Yes but I what to specified the size and the nuber of files suppose to dynamic?

Comment: well this is something you cant do, you have to tell sql server where you want to take the backup and how many files you want to take this backup on.